# Sales Invoice reset by new year

Tags: invoice

it's possible to reset invoice id by new year?

For instance: `1,2,3,4 -> 2014` and then `1,2,3,4 -> 2015`.

The field `increment_id` of `sales_flat_invoice` seem to avoid this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, when you just change the value in `eav_entity_store`. But the problem is, that the increment id needs to be unique. So the better alternative is to prefix it by the year `201400001` and reset it at the end of 2015 to `201500001` or `150000001` so you can have more orders.

To do this, you just have to set the increment_prefix to the current year and the `increment_last_id` to `0*1`